# PDF on popup not working on mac machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos-sierra

I am trying to open pdf on popup window using below code

```
  $(document).on("click", ".btnOpenWindowpaid", function () {
           var fileName = $(this).attr("data-path");
           var fileNameIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
           var OnlyFileName = fileName.substr(fileNameIndex);
           var iframe = '<object type="application/pdf" data="' + fileName + '" width="100%" height="420">No Support</object>'
           $.createModal({
               title: OnlyFileName,
               message: iframe,
               closeButton: true,
               scrollable: false
           });

       });

 (function (a) {
           a.createModal = function (b) {
               defaults = { title: "", message: "Your Message Goes Here!", closeButton: true, scrollable: false };
               var b = a.extend({}, defaults, b); var c = (b.scrollable === true) ? 'style="max-height: 420px;overflow-y: auto;"' : "";
               html = '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">'; html += '<div class="modal-dialog">'; html += '<div class="modal-content">';
               html += '<div class="modal-header">'; html += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>';
               if (b.title.length > 0) { html += '<h4 class="modal-title">' + b.title + "</h4>" } html += "</div>";
               html += '<div class="modal-body" ' + c + ">"; html += b.message; html += "</div>"; html += '<div class="modal-footer">';
               if (b.closeButton === true) { html += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>' } html += "</div>";
               html += "</div>"; html += "</div>"; html += "</div>"; a("body").prepend(html); a("#myModal").modal().on("hidden.bs.modal",
                   function () { a(this).remove() })
           }
       })(jQuery);
```

This code opens pdf on modal popup perfectly on windows machine browsers. when i tested with mac machine. its not working.

How can i open pdf in modal pop irrespective of operating systems and browsers ?

Answer (score 0):

Safari/Chrome have built-in pop-up blockers that stop this from working. The only javascript that is allowed to open a new window in Safari/Chrome is javascript directly attached to click handlers (and other direct user input handlers). In past versions people figured out some ways to cheat (like generating some other element -- a form or div -- and simulating user input with javascript), but newer versions are smarter about detecting this. I'd recommend re-configuring things so that you don't use a delayed pop-up -- that is the kind of thing that can generally be jarring to a user after all.

Work around would be

I got around this by checking the return value of window.open() for undefined. If that is true call alert() with a message for the user to to disable their popup blocker.

var myWin = window.open([args]);

if (myWin == undefined)
   alert('Please disable your popup blocker');